# Quiz on Android / iOS Game

Tags: game-identification

I have played this game but I´ve lost my phone and forgot the name.

## What I know

- This game is available for iOS and Android
- This game is a quiz battle
- This game has levesl.
- This game has a lot of genres (From games to anime)

## Pics

[image: End of the quiz]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After intensive google reverse image identifying and running through some blogs, I'm sure that the game is called [**QuizUp**](https://www.quizup.com/en).

[image: A banner of the game]

You can download it for free for,

Windows Phone and Windows 10 (PC, Tablet and Phone) [here](https://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=6afc48f8-07c8-493d-b85d-f363511719a4)

iOS [here](http://app.appsflyer.com/id718421443?pid=QuizUp_web_iOS_btn&c=app_store_btn_quizup_web)

Android [here](http://app.appsflyer.com/com.quizup.core?pid=QuizUp_web_Android_btn&c=google_play_btn_quizup_web)

Amazon Appstore [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KWZ88N4)